# Quarkus failed to build:Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building

Tags: quarkus

i have simple Quarkus app, which has an endpoint, once it receive request, it'll send a message to kafka, in order to connect to Kafka, it need to download secrets from Azure keyvault.

when I ran

```
./mvnw package -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true and
./mvnw package -Pnative
```

both failed with this error:

```
[2/7] Performing analysis...  [21:59:23,316 INFO  [com.azu.cor.imp.jac.JacksonVersion] Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.1, jackson-core=2.13.1, jackson-databind=2.13.1, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.1, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.1, azure-core=1.25.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot
]
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion the class was requested to be initialized at run time (subtype of io.netty.util.AbstractReferenceCounted). To see why io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion
io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from feature io.quarkus.runner.AutoFeature.beforeAnalysis with 'FileDescriptor.class'). To see why io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor
io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from feature io.quarkus.runner.AutoFeature.beforeAnalysis with 'Epoll.class'). To see why io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll
```

...

in the app i have dependency on

```
azure-keyvault: 4.3.7
azure-identity.version: 1.4.4
```

my setup:

```
java -version
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 17.0.2+8-jvmci-22.0-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 17.0.2+8-jvmci-22.0-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
dyi@Dan2742 ise-shared-quarkus-1 % mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec
Java version: 13.0.6, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-13.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

can anyone tell what the error is about? and how can i fix it?

Comment: These Azure dependencies do not support native, unfortunately. You can use them in JVM mode without any issue.
When building native, some classes are initialized at build time, and the memory (static members) is written directly in the executable. Some classes do not support this, and that's the case with the one you have.

Comment: BTW, make sure you have the quarkus-netty extension on the classpath. It might not fix everything but will likely remove some issues.

Comment: @Clement, added quarkus-netty extension, but it still failed for the same reason. So I  cannot build a docker image at all ? That's too bad, we use MS Azure thus use lots of Azure lib.

Comment: Yes, these libraries are not compatible with native, at least not without a lot of work. I guess it's using reactive-netty under the hood. I've seen some work around it, but never completely done.